# Set items while uploading a file in a document library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, client-object-model

I am using JavaScript to upload a file in a document library, like this

```
clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();
oList = oWebsite.get_lists().getByTitle("The_List_Where_I_Upload");

fileCreateInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
fileCreateInfo.set_overwrite(true);
fileCreateInfo.set_url(filename);
fileCreateInfo.set_content(content); /*the content is generated somewhere else, it's not important in this question*/

this.newFile = oList.get_rootFolder().get_files().add(fileCreateInfo);

clientContext.load(this.newFile);
```

The code works, but let's say, at the same time when I upload the file I also want to set the value of another column in the document library, for example Username or User Address.

I tried with  `fileCreateInfo.set_item('Username', value); but it throws an error saying

> set_item is not a function.

Is it possible to set other columns values while uploading a file to a document library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After upload you can do it as

```
clientContext.load(this.newFile, 'ListItemAllFields');
var item = this.newFile.get_listItemAllFields();

item.set_item('Username', value);
item.Update();
clientContext.ExecuteQuery...
```